# How can I specify Memcached options to compress the cached data with C#.Net?

Tags: c#, .net, memcached, enyim

I have ASP.Net project and I'm using Memcached for data and session caching. I also need to use the compress options of Memcached. I'd appreciate that if you can share your comments with me! I have found some sites but they don't have any c#.Net code samples.

Comment: which memcached client-library are you using?

Comment: That's Enyim Memcached Client.

Comment: k; last time I looked, memcached didn't have compression at the *server*; has this changed? or is this a feature of the *client library*? or is it something you are doing manually?

Comment: I think it's a feature of the client library, so that when you change the compression option in you application, then your compression options tell Memcached to compress the data if it can. There is an article here about this feature. http://benrobb.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/memcached.pdf

Comment: @NurhakKaya - As @MarcGravell says, the compression is made on the client side. If you look at the beitmemcached [source code](http://code.google.com/p/beitmemcached/source/browse/trunk/ClientLibrary/Serializer.cs) you can see how it's made (check the `Serializer` class' `Serialize` method).

Comment: @PHeiberg I have checked the Serializer class of BeITMemcached client which looks pretty good actually but I want to find another solution with Enyim If I can. Thank you guys for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this comparison](http://sysdot.wordpress.com/tag/enyim/) of memcached clients, the Enyim doesn't provide built in compression support.

The beitmemcached library however has. The [Feature Description](http://code.google.com/p/beitmemcached/wiki/Features) says it's automatically compressing all objects exceeding a certain threshhold.

> Compression
>
> The client also supports compression for storing large
>   objects. It uses the built-in DeflateStream compression, which
>   compresses data into the Deflate format. If the bytearray that is to
>   be stored is larger than the value specified in the property
>   CompressionThreshold, the data will be compressed before stored in the
>   memcached servers, and automatically decompressed when retrived. The
>   default value of CompressionThreshold is 128 kB.